# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /etc/apache2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/smart_ip/includes/smart_ip.utility.inc on line 454

Tags: php, apache-httpd, php5

I'm using centos 6.7, http 2.4.17, mysql 5.1, php 5.5.30. web page is working fine but at bottom it is giving below error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /etc/apache2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/smart_ip/includes/smart_ip.utility.inc on line 454
```

I've installed zlib through source code but still its not enabling it after configuring php, restarting apache and system.

```
php -i|grep -i zlib
gzip compression => disabled (install ext/zlib)
```

How to enable gzip compression ?

Comment: I think your PHP is not linked with zlib properly. Can you post `ldd $(which php)` onto pastebin?

Comment: # ldd $(which php)
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff39ff5000)
 libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f3eb5ffd000)
 libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f3eb5de3000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3eb5bda000)
 libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f3eb59b4000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3eb579e000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3eb5519000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3eb5315000)
 libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f3eb50fc000)
 libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f3eb4da8000)

Comment: libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3eb4b8b000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3eb47f7000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3eb623f000)
 libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f3eb45f3000)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Due to libpng12 pulled in there is no clear way to indicate that php is configured without zlib. Does your `php -i` list configure parameters?

Comment: Have you installed the `php55w-common` package, specifically, `php-zlib`?

Comment: I've recompiled php with zlib and all other options which was previously used. This solves my issue. Thank you guys.